# Replacement in Apache SOLR

Tags: solr, schema, solrcloud

I am trying to replace "-" in a field with a blank space in apache solr. I tried with the below config but it aint working. Any leads would be much appreciated.

```
<field name="animal" type="text_general_replace" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="TRUE"/>

<fieldType name="text_general_replace" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="-" replacement=" " replace="all"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="-" replacement=" " replace="all"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The string I am indexing into animal field is "bat-man" and the string I would like to store in solr is "bat man"

Comment: StandardTokenizerFactory splits or creates the token when it finds the "-". Did you check the analysis page what happens after StandardTokenizerFactory?

Comment: check on the StandardTokenizerFactory on the solr documentation https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_6/tokenizers.html. The StandardTokenizerFactory itself removes the "-" as it splits the the text and creates 2 separate tokens. Do you really need the PatternReplaceFilterFactory?

Comment: The reason why I am planning to remove "-" is because I get issues in highlighting. The highlighting gives results as shown below.   bat-<em class=\"mark\">man</em>

Comment: and the expected highlight output should be bat<em class=\"mark\">man</em> . We get issues while integrating in our application in UI and So I need the "-" to be removed.

Comment: The HIghtlighet get the data because the field is marked as stored. It will not get the data the way it is indexed. The fields data/text is stored as it is without any manipulation. The indexed data is used only while searching.

Comment: if the data is not marked as stored, then the highlight does not work at all !

Comment: I know that...You can manipulate the the way the data is stored...You can manipulate the data the way you want to index....SO in your case nothing can be done on solr side...Hope its clear

Answer (score 0):

The Highlighting gets the data because the field is marked as stored.
The field which is marked as stored, the data/text is stored as it is without any mutation or tokenization for retrieval and highlighting the text.

The fields text will not mutation/tokenization the data the way it is done at the time of indexing.

The fields data/text is stored as it is without any manipulation.

The indexed data is used only while searching and we can control the mutation/tokenization by applying the different tokenizers and filters.

Comment: Any ideas on which tokenizers should be used ?

Comment: For your current issue there is not question of tokenizers. You get the data/text as it, as the data is stored as it is passed to solr.

Comment: so the data can't be modified as  **bat man**  from **bat-man** , right ?

Comment: yes it wont be modified for the highlighting...it will same original text.